# "delete account" documentation is out of date

Tags: support, user-accounts

https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

But the top bar is now different.

Comment: What do you mean the top bar is now different?

Comment: No, the bar is consistent.

Comment: I have heard on another site that the appearance of the top bar changes at a certain reputation threshold.

Answer (score -2):

The top bar is the same: "Profile   Activity   Edit Profile & Settings".
However, I see "Job alerts" and "OTHER \ Privileges" in my account. These items are missing in the image. So, some action might be needed, but it's not urgent.